# Multiple Array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-1a38bb558a59802a54ebd4b27c91431e-1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Attacco rapido
            )

        [wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-0ad0b877a16a24fc4958374f171ef112-1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bordo bianco
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-1a38bb558a59802a54ebd4b27c91431e-1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Attacco rapido
            )

        [wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-3b2241533b2c56891d3fd57718409b85-1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Supporti regolabili
            )

    )
```

)

how i can get array with only values (Attacco rapido,Bordo bianco,Attacco rapido, Supporti regolabili)?

Answer (score 5):

using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) and passing `$list` by reference to fill it by the new values

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$list) {
    $list[] = $value;
});

print_r($list);
```

Output :-

```
Array (
    [0] => Attacco rapido
    [1] => Bordo bianco
    [2] => Attacco rapido
    [3] => Supporti regolabili
)
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/uhGlk